# (NODE.JS & HTML) creating 2 outcomes on textarea input

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, textarea

So, I was again working on my bot website thingy that replies to and relies on textarea input, but then when i tried to test it with two commands, my code stopped working for one command. I don't understand what happened, so any help would be welcomed with the most open hands.
My code:

```js
function reply() {
  const rplyBox = document.getElementById('rplyBox')
  const input = document.getElementById('msgBox').value;
  if (input === "help") {
    const embed = document.createElement("div");
    embed.classList.add("w3-round-xxlarge", "w3-margin-top", "w3-animate-opacity", "w3-margin-bottom", "w3-margin-right", "w3-margin-left")
    const title = document.createElement("h1")
    title.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Help"));
    const desc = document.createElement("h3")
    desc.appendChild(document.createTextNode("All of my commands!"));
    const field1 = document.createElement("h6")
    field1.classList.add("w3-border", "w3-topbar", "w3-bottombar", "w3-leftbar", "w3-rightbar", "w3-round-xlarge", "w3-border-black")
    field1.appendChild(document.createTextNode("kill"));
    const br = document.createElement('br');
    field1.appendChild(br);
    field1.appendChild(document.createTextNode('{name of the person to kill (figuratively)}'));
    embed.appendChild(title);
    embed.appendChild(desc);
    embed.appendChild(field1);
    rplyBox.appendChild(embed);
  } else if (input === "kill") {
    const cmdInput = input.value.split("\n");
    const person = cmdInput[1];
    const embed = document.createElement("div");
    embed.classList.add("w3-round-xxlarge", "w3-margin-top", "w3-animate-opacity", "w3-margin-bottom", "w3-margin-right", "w3-margin-left")
    const title = document.createElement("h1")
    title.appendChild(document.createTextNode("You killed " + person + "!"));
    const desc = document.createElement("h3")
    desc.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Well, they must've deserved it."));
    embed.appendChild(title);
    embed.appendChild(desc);
    rplyBox.appendChild(embed);
  }
}
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.main {
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-right: 5%;
}

* {
  font-family: monospace;
}

t {
  font-size: 8vw;
}


body {
  animation: blueGrad;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: 6s;
}

.sticky {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>replit</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
  
<body style="background-image: url('https://bot.valueyu.repl.co/bg.mp4'); background-size: cover;">
  <div class="main">
    <t>bot.valueyu</t>
    <p>bot.valueyu is a bot made by Aarav Saini/Valueyu. For commmands type "<span
        class="w3-text-white">help</span>".</p>
    <br>
    <p>Each command disappears after 5 seconds. Some commands which need time might last longer, In which case, the time will be defined in the bottom-left corner.</p>
    <hr>
    <textarea class="w3-round-large w3-bar w3-margin-top sticky" id="msgBox"></textarea>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <button id="submit" onClick="reply()" class="w3-round-xxlarge w3-button sticky">Send</button>
    <hr>
    <div class="w3-bar w3-white w3-round-large" id="rplyBox">
        
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Once again, any help is appreciated. Like alot.

Comment: If your input is "kill", it enters the else statement, splits on a newline (giving ["kill"]) then tries to access the second element (which doesn't exist, because your input was "kill" that doesn't contain any newlines). If your input is "kill test" then it skips your if/else entirely because "kill test" is neither "help" nor "kill".

You need to split your input before your if/else, then pass the first element to your if/else statement.

I'd also recommend looking in to how the console and debug tools in a browser work as they will help you fix this without needing to ask.

Comment: @Alex it still dosen't seem to work. I posted the code in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

@Alex so now my code is this:

```js
function reply() {
  const rplyBox = document.getElementById('rplyBox');
  const input = document.getElementById('msgBox').value;
  const killCmdInput = document.getElementById("msgBox").value.split(' ');
  if (input === "help") {
    const embed = document.createElement("div");
    embed.classList.add("w3-round-xxlarge", "w3-margin-top", "w3-animate-opacity", "w3-margin-bottom", "w3-margin-right", "w3-margin-left")
    const title = document.createElement("h1")
    title.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Help"));
    const desc = document.createElement("h3")
    desc.appendChild(document.createTextNode("All of my commands!"));
    const field1 = document.createElement("h6")
    field1.classList.add("w3-border", "w3-topbar", "w3-bottombar", "w3-leftbar", "w3-rightbar", "w3-round-xlarge", "w3-border-black")
    field1.appendChild(document.createTextNode("kill"));
    const br = document.createElement('br');
    field1.appendChild(br);
    field1.appendChild(document.createTextNode('{name of the person to kill (figuratively)}'));
    embed.appendChild(title);
    embed.appendChild(desc);
    embed.appendChild(field1);
    rplyBox.appendChild(embed);
  } else if (input === "kill") {
    const person = killCmdInput[1];
    const embed = document.createElement("div");
    embed.classList.add("w3-round-xxlarge", "w3-margin-top", "w3-animate-opacity", "w3-margin-bottom", "w3-margin-right", "w3-margin-left")
    const title = document.createElement("h1")
    title.appendChild(document.createTextNode("You killed " + person + "!"));
    const desc = document.createElement("h3")
    desc.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Well, they must've deserved it."));
    embed.appendChild(title);
    embed.appendChild(desc);
    rplyBox.appendChild(embed);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>replit</title>
  <link href="https://bot.valueyu.repl.co/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
  
<body style="background-image: url('https://bot.valueyu.repl.co/bg.mp4'); background-size: cover;">
  <div class="main">
    <t>bot.valueyu</t>
    <p>bot.valueyu is a bot made by Aarav Saini/Valueyu. For commmands type "<span
        class="w3-text-white">help</span>".</p>
    <br>
    <p>Each command disappears after 5 seconds. Some commands which need time might last longer, In which case, the time will be defined in the bottom-left corner.</p>
    <hr>
    <textarea class="w3-round-large w3-bar w3-margin-top sticky" id="msgBox"></textarea>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <button id="submit" onClick="reply()" class="w3-round-xxlarge w3-button sticky">Send</button>
    <hr>
    <div class="w3-bar w3-white w3-round-large" id="rplyBox">
        
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

but it still doesn't seem to work.
**EDIT:** It now works, thanks @Alex!

Comment: You are still checking your full input in your if/else, not the first element of your input array (the command). See https://jsfiddle.net/ma42b68o/

Comment: TYYYYYY!!!!!!!!